# WicketPDF rendering table not aligned properly and footer place at last page

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I am generating pdf report from html page, I created the layout with header and footer separately , I need header only for first page and footer at last page, I tried some
scripts for that but it is not working, and how to avoid page break inside table row and I need border for each page without breaking table row is breaking like as shown in an image.

[image]

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf {
     render :pdf => "Report",
            :template => 'layouts/pdf_layout.pdf.erb',
            :layout => 'pdf_layout.pdf.erb',
            :margin => {:bottom => 35},
            :page_size => 'A4',
            :header => {:content => render_to_string({:template => 'layouts/header.pdf.erb'})},
            :footer => {:content => render_to_string({:template => 'layouts/footer.pdf.erb'})}
  }
end
```

Any other suggestion

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your relevant `code`? and what is not not working?

Comment: Please see the render sample code I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page break issues can usually be mitigated with a few css rules, well placed:

```
div.alwaysbreak { page-break-before: always; }
div.nobreak:before { clear:both; }
div.nobreak{ page-break-inside: avoid;
  /* http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=9#c21 */
}
```

So, one of the interesting things is that these rules don't work on table elements, so if you have a table and want to prevent cells from being split in half, you can wrap each table row with a `<div>`.

This is certainly not clean & semantic, but you can do it like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <div class='nobreak'>
      <tr>
        <th>One</th><th>Two</th>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <div class = 'nobreak'>
      <tr>
        <td>Uno</td><td>Dos</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

To get your page borders to line up perfectly, you are probably going to have to set it to a fixed height with CSS with an `.awaysbreak`, then have some javascript that computes the height of the table and breaks it into chunks based on height.

Maybe it's just because your table so far is so simple, but this looks like it might be a good candidate to try using [prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) with. You'll have better control of those types of layout issues.

There's a railscast for it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn).