# Issue with pdf generation with content as tables using wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I used the gem **wicked_pdf** ,  **wkhtmltopdf-binary** to generate pdf.

-The table rows are not rendered properly when the page breaks.

-I want to use a common header for all pages and render the footer only for the last page.
[image]

Comment: Which version of the wkhtmltopdf binary? If you can, switch the binary to 0.12.x, the table breaking there is better than in earlier versions. This is one of the very difficult and long standing issues with wkhtmltopdf and might even be unfixable. If you control the HTML, I suggest that you manually break the table into smaller parts.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988738/wicketpdf-rendering-table-not-aligned-properly-and-footer-place-at-last-page