# wicked pdf css bounding box?

Tags: pdf, wicked-pdf

In PDF generators you can normally describe a bounding box where if there is overflow it goes to a new page and you can include the content that wrapped it again.

I'm trying to figure out how to elegantly do this in Wicked, since we have a new requirement to allow users to generate their own PDFs from HTML.

The layout is roughly as follows:

[ address / logo ]

[ list of items purchased ]

[ footer ]

All the regions are a fixed size. With a handful of items there is no issue. If there are more than will fit in the region designated for the items purchased it cannot overflow. It needs to generate a new page break and put the overflow items on the following page (with the same header and footer wrapper).

I'm not sure there is a way to get a div's overflow to paginate like that in CSS though. (Prawn can do it, but it doesn't accept HTML). I don't know that something is going to overflow until it's rendered too, just knowing the count of items isn't enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988738/wicketpdf-rendering-table-not-aligned-properly-and-footer-place-at-last-page/25039466#25039466

Comment: So it turns out that since Wicked uses wkhtmltopdf for the backend, and Webkit has awful support for page breaking - I've looked at other libraries (Prince). Using the table, thead, tfoot, tbody I'm able to get close to what I want. Getting the footer at the bottom of a page with tfoot is still problematic but it's better than nothing.

Comment: If you want to use Prince without paying for a license, you can use the http://docraptor.com web service. Also, you could calculate the height of your rows in advance and use some javascript to see if the next row puts it over the page boundary, then break the page early. The CSS rules I posted in the linked question above can help there.

Answer (score 0):

Webkit doesn't really have good support for page breaking.  I found out from their own page: "The current page breaking algorithm of WebKit leaves much to be desired.
Basically webkit will render everything into one long page, and then cut it up
into pages. This means that if you have two columns of text where one is
vertically shifted by half a line. Then webkit will cut a line into to pieces
display the top half on one page. And the bottom half on another page. It will
also break image in two and so on.  If you are using the patched version of QT
you can use the CSS page-break-inside property to remedy this somewhat. There is
no easy solution to this problem, until this is solved try organizing your HTML
documents such that it contains many lines on which pages can be cut cleanly."